# Node.js Overwriting a file

Tags: node.js, heroku, io, filesystems

I know it is a simple question, but haven't been able to find anything useful on this one.

How do you use `fs.createWriteStream(dst)` to overwrite a file? (note that the app is hosted on heroku)

I tried `{flags: 'w'}` or `{flags: 'r+'}` even `{flags: 'wb'}`. None of these worked, I keep getting 
`Error: File uploads/1.txt exists.`

Comment: `{flags: 'w'}` should do it.  Permissions issue?

Comment: it was actually my fault, I copied some code online and didn't notice how it was handling overwrites. It first did a fs.stat, and if there was no error (i.e. file exists) it would just do `cb(new Error('File already exists');`. So I ended up just commenting out that line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options):

> Modifying a file rather than replacing it may require a flags mode of r+ rather than the default mode w.

So `{flags: 'w'}` should work. This sounds like a permissions issue?

Are you able to do an `fs.unlink()` on that file? This should test the permissions on that file if you don't have access to the computer directly.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the flag 'w' set by default ? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options