# Altering file using readline in NodeJS results in blank file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to programmatically alter a file as part of my `postinstall` npm script.

As such, I've written a utility to search for a string and comment the line of code out, however the resulting file is blank.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const readline = require('readline');
const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'test.txt');
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: readStream,
  output: writeStream,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  console.log(line);

  // check if the line contains the code I want to comment out
  if (line.includes('test string')) {
    line = '// ' + line;
  }
  writeStream.write(line + '\n');
});

rl.on('close', () => {
  readStream.close();
  writeStream.close();
});
```

What am I doing wrong? My console statement is never logged for one and the ReadStream object reports `bytesRead: 0`, although the path to the file is correct.

Comment: Opening the write stream is probably immediately truncating the file. Generally, to do something like what you're doing, you'd write to a temporary file and then when finished you'd rename the temporary file to replace the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code lies in the way you're setting up the write stream. By using

```
fs.createWriteStream(filePath)
```

directly, you're essentially overwriting the contents of the file with an empty stream. This is why you end up with a blank file.

Here you can found more information
[Node.js Overwriting a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995536/node-js-overwriting-a-file)

Comment: Thank you. Adding the `{ flags: 'r+' }` option to `createReadStream` fixed it for me.